# iTunes Airplay not working when connected to VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, itunes, airplay

I'm having trouble getting airplay to work in iTunes when connected to my work network through VPN (error -15000). It works fine if I disconnect the VPN...

Any ideas how I can fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VPN may be the type that "takes over" your computer's Internet connection and pipes everything through the VPN.

Depending on the type of VPN and how your workplace's network admin has configured it, it may or may not be possible to tell your VPN client to not send local traffic through the LAN.  Look for any option in your VPN client such as "Enable local LAN" or similar.